# Internal Server Error (500) on Google Cloud Run with Websockets and Buildpacks concerning Gunicorn

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, websocket, gunicorn, google-cloud-run

Hi all I have a python project which I've been trying to deploy on **Cloud Run** since 24 hours non-stop and can't get it to work. I've connected my git repo to **Cloud Build** with **buildpacks** . Since my app uses websockets I've Allowed unauthenticated invocations, CPU is always allocated,  Minimum number of instances is 1 with 1GiB of Memory. It builds correctly without any errors but when I visit the link I get an Internal Server Error (500).

*Error:*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 135, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 178, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
```

*requirements.txt:*

```
beautifulsoup4
duckduckgo_search
fastapi
google_cloud_aiplatform
langchain
langchain_community
langchain_core
python-dotenv
requests
tqdm
uvicorn
faiss-cpu
sentence-transformers
pandas
openpyxl
arxiv
PyMuPDF
websockets
```

*.env:*

```
PROJECT_ID = "ancient-wave-414112"
LOCATION = "us-central1"
CONFIG_PATH = "./config.json"
```

*main.py:*

```
from backend.api import app
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
load_dotenv()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    os.environ['KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK']='True'
    uvicorn.run(app, host="localhost", port=8000)
```

I've tried removing the package versions and set min instances to 1 as per these solutions below but nothing worked:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/generative-ai/issues/198
[Google Cloud Run Gunicorn Multi-Threaded Django Request Blocked on Cold Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913643/google-cloud-run-gunicorn-multi-threaded-django-request-blocked-on-cold-start)

Comment: Verify that your Cloud Run service has the necessary permissions to access resources (e.g., Cloud Storage, databases) your application might use and 

if your application relies on external services, check for network connectivity and firewall rules that might prevent communication. 

After making changes, restart your Cloud Run service to ensure they take effect.